# Three variable data table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a financial model in excel that projects the ending cash balance for each of 12 months.  Each column represents a month starting in January.  The rows are:

1. Opening Cash Balance:  In January, this is a number.  For the remaining months, Opening Cash Balance = previous months Ending Cash Balance.
2. Revenue:  There are two variables, one for the amount and one for the starting month.  Once revenue starts, it continues at the same amount.
3. Monthly Expense:  This is a variable entered in January where the following months all equal the January input.
4. Net Income:  = Revenue - Expense
5. Ending Cash Balance = Opening Cash Balance + Net Income

I want to see the December Ending Cash Balance produced by all combinations of Amount of Revenue, Timing of Revenue and Monthly Expense subject to the following constraints:

1. Revenue must be >= zero and cannot be > 5x January’s Opening Cash Balance.
2. Monthly Expense must be >= zero and cannot be > 5x Revenue for that month.

The output should be in a table so that I can see the results of all of the combinations.

I want to use the model to see what combinations of the three variables will get me to a cash balance in December of >= zero.

Comment: what is your question?... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Comment: @Saga Noren ,,, I think that U are confused what to be asked,,,, [Check this,,](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit] your post & be clear all about your need,,, I think that U are looking for a Spreadsheet where U can handle your financial Data.

Comment: This question is more about mathematical modeling, not about the use of Excel.

Comment: Also, instead of describing your data, consider uploading a screencap to http://imgur.com and linking to it, or better yet, including it as editable text in a table

Comment: Assessment by @Emily is spot on. You probably need to consider redoing your table, or you need to build a VBA to loop through all the possible input combinations and output that along with the result to your results table. Unless there are just a finite number of combinations, a table format may be an exercise in futility; consider doing this graphically.